# How to fetch all emails of all users in an Organization in Office365/Outlook API

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office365, office365api, outlook-restapi

I am currently able to fetch Emails for single user using:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailfolders/inbox/messages
```

How do we fetch all emails in an organization in a single call? I do not want to loop through every user and fetch their emails.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. You will need to process all mailboxes one at a time:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user@domain.demo/mailfolders/inbox/messages
```